# Show that $\int f(x)dx=\int g(u)du$

Tags: calculus, integration

Dose anyone know how to do this?

If a function $f(x)$ can be written $f(x)=g(u(x))du(x)/dx$ for a suitable function $u(x)$, show that $\int f(x)dx=\int g(u)du$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $z = u(x)$ on the right integral.